# Unable to display menu icons in android application

Tags: android, icons

Please see below the menu.xml file I have created , which I have kept under res-> menu->  folder

```
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_About"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_about"
      android:title="@string/About" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_Settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
      android:title="@string/Settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_Exit"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_exit"
      android:title="@string/Exit" />
```

I have kept the icon_about.png , icon_settings.png , icon_exit.png files under res-> drawable-hdpi ,drawable-ldpi , drawable-mdpi , drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi folders but when my application runs, these icons don't show up.  Please tell me if I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this in your activity:

```
@Override   
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    Inflate the menu; // this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);       
    return true;    
}
```

Comment: This is the question, it should be in comment

Comment: @Williams: it is not a question, but solution suggestion. So, it looks OK to me.

Comment: IMO, it should be in comment

Comment: @Williams: why if Pinki attempts to answer the question? You might be confused by the question mark, and I agree that it is better to avoid that, but unfortunately many people use that even in answers. Just suggest an edit to modify that.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have used the icons of correct sizes. for option menus the desired sizes are

```
ldpi 32 x 32 px
mdpi: 36 x 36 px
hdpi: 48 x 48 px
xhdpi: 64 x 64 px
```

Comment: Yes this was also needed along with ShowAsAction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have kept the icon_about.png , icon_settings.png , icon_exit.png
>   files under res-> drawable-hdpi ,drawable-ldpi , drawable-mdpi ,
>   drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi folders but when my application runs,
>   these icons don't show up. Please tell me if I am missing something.

=> You haven't included  `android:showAsAction` attribute in all the menu items.

Comment: @user3060037 if this has helped you then as per the SO rules, you should accept/upvote answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

open your main Activity class file and type following code. In the following code each menu item is identified by its ID in switch case statement.

```
public class MenusActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    // Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {

        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.menu_About:

            Toast.makeText(MenusActivity.this, "about is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Toast.makeText(MenusActivity.this, "settings is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;


        case R.id.menu_Exit:
            Toast.makeText(MenusActivity.this, "Exit is Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;



        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }    

}
```

. Finally run your project by right clicking on your project.On Android Emulator click on Menu Button to launch menu.

Comment: I already have this code written in MainActivity class. The menu options are working fine as when I select About menu option, a message "about is selected" is displayed. It's my icons which are not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/web_link"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_About"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Web link"/>
```

You have to add android:showAsAction="always" if you want always..there other option too. like "never", which used to never show the icon if you want they can add programatically,and other "ifroom" if there are place than this menu item will appear